dynamic values not showing up in EmailJS emails
I'm using EmailJS for creating and sending email messages.
Right now, when I submit data from a form, a message arrives in my Gmail account as expected, but the dynamic values found in {{ }} in the EmailJS template barely show up.
Here's an example:
my template looks like this:
Hi,
You've got the message from:

{{user_email}} 

{{message_subject}}

{{message}}

And here's the code of using these dynamic values:
<input
   type="text"
   name="message_subject"
   placeholder="Your message subject..."
   {...register("messageSubject")}
/>

<input
    type="email"
    name="user_email"
    placeholder="Your email..."
    {...register("userEmail")}
/>

<textarea
    name="message"
    placeholder="Describe your problem or question..."
    className={styles.textarea}
    {...register("userMessage")}
/>

When I submitted this data, I only received the message variable, the other two are not showing up
Am I missing something, i guess I'm using name attributes correctly, and they're matching to the variable's names
UPDATE: nevermind, now message is not showing up as well =(

The {...register("messageSubject")} can override attributes. Try to move the name attribute to the end.
<input
   type="text"
   placeholder="Your message subject..."
   {...register("messageSubject")}
   name="message_subject"
/>


yeah, yesterday i did figure out, that handleSubmit and register function of react-hook-form are the reason my emails are not working, so right now i removed them and trying to find a way to validate form's data without overwriting it with validation. Your suggestion seems interesting, so i'll try, thanks

and yeah, you actually helped me. I figured i might not even use name attr. Instead, i'll use register's string as a dynamic value. So in my template i've changed dyn vals to match register's vals, and yeah, it worked for me. Spasibo so much for helping.
